# jquery each() function not working as intended

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through all the inputs in my form and if the input does not contain a value, then do a couple of things.

Here's my code so far,

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if($(this+'[value!=""]')) {
        $('.requiredMark').hide();
        $(this).after(checkMark);   
    }       
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Well, what's the problem with your current code? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: `this` is not a string here, but you seem to think it is.

Comment: Your `if` statement is completely wrong.

Comment: i think you want $(this).val()

Comment: Well the current code applies the hide() and after() functions to all the inputs, instead of just the ones with items already in them.

Comment: @Doorknob - Free waffles? Doesn't sound like a problem to me :P

Comment: Heard you got some free waffles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That if-statement is wrong. `this` will not refer to a string. Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value:

```
 $('input').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);

     if($this.val() != "") {
         $('.requiredMark').hide();
         $this.after(checkMark);   
     }       
 });
```

Comment: @DavidThomas Yep, but he needs a jQuery object two lines below so why not use the same object both times? I think it's cleaner.

Comment: Oh, there's no real harm done, just that he only needs the jQuery object *if* the `value`/`val()` is equal to an empty string (in which case I'd probably go with `this.value.length === 0`); the *assessment* is cheaper with the plain DOM method, but once in the `if`, then you've got the issue of creating the `$(this)` object. So, six of one, half a dozen of the other, really.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing $(this+'[value!=""]'), you can use

```
if($(this).val()===''){
   //if the element has empty value, do something here
}
```

Comment: Also, if you want to check whitespace, you can do $(this).val().trim()

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
 $('input').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()){
                $('.requiredMark').hide();
                $(this).after(checkMark);   
            }       
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your input field with `$(this)`

to get its value its `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').val(function(index,el){
    if(el.length){
        alert('Has value')
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VpmAv/